# Django REST Framework substituting 'null' for 0 in IntegerField

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model in Django with an IntegerField:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I use Django REST Framework's model serializer:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

The JSON that is created by the REST framework is:

```
{
    "number": null
}
```

The problem is that this fails validation if I just post it back exactly as received. What do I change in order to have the received JSON object use `0` instead of `null` for an object?

Comment: There should be no null field in the database if you have a default of 0. Did by chance add rows to your database before adding the default modifier to your integer field?

Comment: No, I simply created an object and the database shows a value of '0' for the entity's field.

Answer (score 7):

As Mark Galloway commented, null will appear if you have null data in your database. You can solve this by either by changing the validation login in the serializer:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    number = models.IntegerField(initial=0, allow_null=True)
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

or by changing how data is serialized back to the user:

```
class MyIntegerField(serializers.IntegerField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        if value is None:
            return 0
        return super(MyIntegerField, self).to_representation(value)

class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    number = MyIntegerField(initial=0)
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

Comment: The value in the database is not null, but the form created by the REST framework is leaving the value empty. I'm not sure what's different now, but the value in the JSON for an entity created a different way is actually 0, but it still shows up as empty in the form. So the value in the form seems to be empty regardless of whether the entity that reaches the serializer is null or 0.

Answer (score 0):

I created this Serializer field to render null values as 0.

```py
from rest_framework import fields, serializers

class IntegerDefaultField(fields.IntegerField):
    def get_attribute(self, instance):
        attibute = super().get_attribute(instance)
        if attibute is None and self.default != fields.empty:
            attibute = self.default
        return attibute

class ExampleSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    number = IntegerDefaultField(default=0)
```

Overriding `to_representation` did not work for me since the Serializer doesn't call that method when the field value is `None`.